# How do I programatically log off the current user and log on as another?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to force a logoff (knowing this is not recommended) of the current interactive (logged-on) user and then login with a new user account (interactive - not using stuff like LogonUser and other impersonation tricks) to simulate someone physically pressing LOGOFF and then selecting a new account to LOGON...?

The issue is that my service creates a new user account programatically - and I need to find a way to create its corresponding user profile. From what I can see the only way that works would be to physically logoff the current user, and then login as the new user (which will create the User Profile for HKCU, Documents & Settings, etc...). Sounds a little crazy but I can't find a better way...

So, I need to find a way to programmatically force the logoff & logon actions (from my running Windows Service under LocalSystem) - I have all the credentials and access rights needed ... Are there system function calls I can use?

For Logoff I think I can use WTSLogoffSession(...), still trying to get it to work but seems promising - however I have no clue what to do about logon...
Alternitively if there is a better approach to solve my problem I am all ears :)

Any help or hints would be much appreciated...
Thanks,

Comment: Is there a valid reason for creating a user account programatically?

Comment: Is there a valid reason to force someone to log off?

Comment: Only so that I can then logon with the other user and force the User Profile (HKCU, Documents & Settings, etc...) to be created... I couldn't find a better way ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has this solution in c++, which you can use to hack a c# solution, or put in a DLL and call it using COM interop.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196070

Comment: Tried that one - and it doesn't seem to work on my systems (both Windows 2000 Pro and Win XP SP2) - I get no errors or exceptions, the account is created, LoadProfile runs - but the User Profile is simply not created.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to logon the user or just create one? For creation you can use

- NetGroupAdd()
- NetUserAdd()
- NetGroupAddUser()
- NetLocalGroupAdd()
- NetLocalGroupAddMember()

APIs

Comment: But from what I know - none of these will create the USER PROFILE for you ... they will logon as the user (which works fine) but no Documents and Settings, no HKEY CURRENT USER, etc... until an interactive login happens (from what I have seen).

Or do one of those methods you list do something special? I have not tried each one yet ...